# Adding @EnableBatchProcessing causes TransactionRequiredException errors

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a Spring Boot 2 application (still in the development stage) running well with JPA, hibernate and so on.  The single persistence test I've got right now goes thru fine.

However, when I add `@EnableBatchProcessing` to the main boot class (the one annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`) I get the following error during the test phase of the maven build:

- `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException`: no transaction is in
  progress

**If I just remove this annotation the test runs successfully again.**

I read somewhere that spring Batch uses a different transaction manager than that used for JPA persistence.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using your own transaction manager via @transactional annotation??

Comment: I use no annotation in the test.  In the live code I use @Transactional.

Comment: If I comment out the test and force creation of the jar, then the application itself works fine.

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: Yes I did, but it did not solve the problem with the test. So I'm just refactoring this nascent batch programming part out into a different micro-service instance.  Because I'll likely have more clashes with other components later as the codebase becomes more complex -- so would be better to factor out into as many separate independent services as is easy and natural to do.  This will make debugging easier too.  Later, once my Spring knowledge is more in-depth I could go on to more complex scenarios.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

This is very simple.`@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation causes Spring Batch to automatically register a transaction manager to use for its transactions, and your `JpaTransactionManager` never gets used. 
**Reason:**
By default, `@EnableBatchProcessing` triggers the creation of a `DataSourceTransactionManager`. This transaction manager knows nothing about JPA/Hibernate which causes the problem you're seeing.

**Solution:**
Now, if you want to change the transaction manager that Spring Batch uses for transactions, you have to implement the interface [BatchConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/BatchConfigurer.html). There is a link to an [example](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-batch-javaconfig/blob/master/src/main/java/de/codecentric/batch/configuration/WebsphereInfrastructureConfiguration.java) where a user has done this. What he is doing is switching the transaction manager to his own transactionmanager.